# How can link one project with multi domains?

Tags: php, laravel

I have Laravel project contains (user front, admin panel) , now in my app the admin panel located in `mydoamin.com/admin`

I need to move the admin panel to subdomain like `admin.mydoamin.com` in the same project! and let the main domain just for user!

Note: I need that to be the same DB all of this stuff!

Comment: You need to configure it with DNS

Comment: simple way , you can use routes for that purpose

Comment: @sta can u please provide an example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Subdomains may be assigned route parameters just like route URIs, allowing you to capture a portion of the subdomain for usage in your route or controller.
>
> ```
> Route::domain('{user}.mydoamin.com')->group(function () {
>    Route::get('/', function ($user, $id) {
>        //
>    });
> });
> ```

see [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-subdomain-routing)

Comment: with this way I do not need to do any config in server or something I should be a ware of!

Comment: yes you can use $user variable to match if user is admin or not `if(strpos($user, 'admin') === 0){`